# Do I need to play The Dark Eye: Chains of Satinav before playing Memoria?

Tags: the-dark-eye-memoria, the-dark-eye-chains-of-satinav

Is Memoria a direct sequel to Chains of Satinav, or is it just a sequel "in spirit?"

Do I need to play Chains of Satinav to understand the story of Memoria?
Will playing Memoria first ruin the storyline of Chains of Satinav?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, stop adding that suggested-order tag until its fate is decided [on the meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12778/162442). Meta tags are heavily scrutinized for their usefulness and this one seems exceptionally useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I've beaten both games, I feel comfortable in answering this.

Memoria is the sequel to Chains of Satinav.  It is technically a continuation of the first game, with most of the same characters.  However, the story itself is almost completely unrelated, and the events of the first game are only mentioned in passing.

Thus, it's completely possible to play Memoria without playing Chains of Satinav first.  However, I wouldn't recommend it, because the ending to Chains of Satinav would be ruined in the first few minutes of Memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Memoria is a direct sequel to Chains of Satinav, following the storyline of Geron the bird catcher as well as introducing a second storyline.